# Using Electron-Updater with a Self-Signed Certificate on MacOS

Tags: electron, electron-builder, apple-developer, electron-updater

*Basically the title.*

Some Context:
I'm working on a simple Electron app which will be used inside of the company I work at. I just got the publisher and update process working on Windows using electron-builder. I am now trying to get it to work on Mac.
I've created a certificate for testing purposes. My question would be if I can use said certificate to sign the app and make electron-updater accept the certificate.
The application will only be used by a few dozen people, so signing up for the Apple Developer program seems like a waste.

Thanks for reading, have a nice day.